# How to confirm mvc kendo grid dataSource read operation is completed?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC kendo marster detail grid pattern where my detail grid has the capability of adding new rows. After each row addition I am Preserving the state of the parent grid (columns, page, pagesize, sort, filter and grouping etc) and call the datasource.read() to reload master grid data and apply the master grid state back to the grid so that user don't have to re-apply any filter, pager etc back again to get up to the page where he/she was prior to the data reload.

After all above, I am trying to expand the row where detail row data is added. I do have the master detail row id but can't access the grid row so that i can perform the expandrow operation.

My detail row grid is inside an ajax form and I am performing master grid datasource read operation on its detail row onSuccess event.

Following is the onSuccess event of the detail row grid

```
    onSuccessTask: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    if (data.status === "error") {
        toastr.error(data.message);
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("#ModalWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
        toastr.success('Operation completed!');

        refreshGrid();

        var taskKey = data.taskKey;

        if (taskKey.length) {
            var dataItem = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(taskKey);
            var row = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
        }
    }
},
```

refreshGrid call is as follow

```
refreshGrid: function () {
    var tGrid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
    var gridDataSource = tGrid.dataSource;
    var gridState = {
        columns: gridDataSource.columns,
        page: gridDataSource.page(),
        pageSize: gridDataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: gridDataSource.sort(),
        filter: gridDataSource.filter(),
        group: gridDataSource.group()
    };

    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([]);
    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    //$('#grid').data("kendoGrid").refresh;

    var tGridOptions = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").options;
    tGridOptions.columns = gridState.columns;
    tGridOptions.dataSource.page = gridState.page;
    tGridOptions.dataSource.pageSize = gridDataSource.pageSize;
    tGridOptions.dataSource.sort = gridDataSource.sort;
    tGridOptions.dataSource.filter = gridState.filter;
    tGridOptions.dataSource.group = gridState.group;
},
```

Everything till this point coming along nicely but when i try to retrieve dataItem from the dataSource by its column value, it is returning null and the reason is, the dataSource i-e. the read operation of the master grid is not completed yet. Can please anyone recommend any solution for this problem?

```
var dataItem = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(taskKey);
```

If I summarize my question after all above explanation, it will be as follow

How I can wait for the MVC kendo grid dataSource Read operation to be completed before I do anything with its data?

Comment: You can check the RequestEnd method!!!

Comment: This dataSource.read is called from few other locations so it will not be possible to track down where the call was from. I will also loose the row id if I even manage to track the calling point.